# Track the number of test cases executed, passed or failed, from dashboard report in email

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I have created a Test Plan to Test Performance testing of API using Jmeter-4.0,
i am using SMTP sampler to send email where i am dynamically sending the Link of dashboard report generated when a Thread is run in background.

I have reviewed all files in report generation folder of dashboard report, but didn't find anything which can solve my problem.

Now i want to add certain information in my email like, number of test cases executed, number of test cases passed and number of test cases failed.

Can anyone help me how i can fetch those data as a variable or any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

The information it being populated on the fly from the .jtl results file, it is not being stored in the structured form anywhere.

So the only way is to parse the .jtl results file and extract the required information from there.

You might find [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) useful, it is capable of parsing the .jtl results file and storing the outcome in [Aggrerate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) or [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) formats which both have `TOTAL` line at the bottom having the number/percentage of passed/failed tests, avg/min/max response time, throughput and other [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

JMeterPluginsCMD Tool (and Synthesis Report if needed) can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]